# Displaying the placeholder in a Select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery-select2

[Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders) is a neat dropdown that combines typing and autocomplete.  If I don't include `<option value="" selected="selected" style="display:none;"></option>` then the first option is always selected by default and the placeholder doesn't show.

Are there any better solutions than this?

Here's what I'm doing in the HTML:

```
<select id="my-dropdown">
  <option value="" selected="selected" style="display:none;"></option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

In a Javascript file:

```
$('#my-dropdown').select2({
  placeholder: 'Choose One'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following after your js code:

```
$('#my-dropdown').val('').trigger('change');
```

or more simply change your js code to:

```
$('#my-dropdown').select2({
  placeholder: 'Choose One'
}).val('').trigger('change');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srajaee/8875dm9m/)

Answer (score 0):

`data-placeholder` attribute works for me, here is an example:

```
<select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Choose One">
    <option value=""></option>
    ...
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working on bootstrap4. Any suggestions?